# Inserting unknown csv file into mysql db using Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, csv

I would like to ask if you know a posibility to insert unknown csv file (unknown headers and number of columns) into mySQL? Or is it only possible with postgresql?
I don't know how to create schema for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB NoSql may suit your needs, NoSql does not support schemas.
If you are dependent of mySql, then save data in vertical table structure.
Difference between vertical and horizontal tables can be found here.

https://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3736011/Using-Vertical-and-Horizontal-Table-Structures-in-Oracle.htm